# Which ValueProviderFactory takes form data?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, model-binding

I have this code in Global.asax:

```
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            //ValueProviderFactories.Factories.RemoveAt(0);
            //I have tried replacing 0 above with 1 to 6.
            //The following Factories are present in ValueProviderFactories.Factories:
            //ChildActionValueProviderFactory
            //FormValueProviderFactory
            //JsonValueProviderFactory
            //RouteDataValueProviderFactory
            //QueryStringValueProviderFactory
            //HttpFileCollectionValueProviderFactory
            //JQueryFormValueProviderFactory
            ValueProviderFactories.Factories.Clear();            
        }
    }
```

I noticed that clearing all the `ValueProviderFactory`, results in form data coming through to an action method as `null`, however when I try to remove one at a time by uncommenting the `RemoveAt` line, and commenting out `ValueProviderFactories.Factories.Clear();` the form data is coming through as non `null`.

Which `ValueProviderFactory` is responsible then for getting the form data?

Here is the view:

```
@using MvcModels.Models
@model IList<AddressSummary>
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<h2>Addresses</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Address</legend>
        <div><label>City:</label>@Html.Editor("[0].City")</div>
        <div><label>Country:</label>@Html.Editor("[0].Country")</div>
    </fieldset>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
}
```

Action method:

```
public ActionResult Address(IList<AddressSummary> addresses)
{
    addresses = addresses ?? new List<AddressSummary>();
    return View(addresses);
}
```

Model:

```
public class AddressSummary
{        
    [Required]
    public string City { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: mvc or web-api?

Comment: @StephenMuecke MVC5

Comment: [FormValueProviderFactory.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/FormValueProviderFactory.cs)

Comment: @StephenMuecke but I removed that when I used ValueProviderFactories.Factories.RemoveAt(1); and the form data still came through into the action method.